# Python Function code works fine but when defined into a function does not work

Tags: python, function

I am currently taking a Udemy course for Python and am on the Functions part of the lesson. I am attempting to create a Black Jack game using functions.

I created a function to prevent duplicate cards from being drawn by comparing them to a list of already drawn cards. If the card drawn is in the list the function calls for a new card to be drawn and again checked against the list. If it is not in the list the function appends the card to the drawn list (used_cards) to be checked further down the code.

The issue I have is that the code actually contained in the function works as intended when placed in the code, however when I define the same code in a function it is not changing the value of a card that is already in the drawn cards list as intended. dupcheck is the name of the function I am referring too. Thank you for any help as I am at a brick wall.

```
import random

cards = {}
cards[1] = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'King', 'Queen', 'Ace']
cards[2] = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'King', 'Queen', 'Ace']
cards[3] = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'King', 'Queen', 'Ace']
cards[4] = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'King', 'Queen', 'Ace']

face_cards = {'Jack': 10, 'King': 10, 'Queen': 10, 'Ace': 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10}

card_class = {1: 'Hearts',
              2: 'Clubs',
              3: 'Spades',
              4: 'Diamonds'}


# Draws a random card from the deck
def rndm_card():
    class_string = random.randint(1, 4)
    rndmcard = random.randint(0, 12)
    card_name = cards[class_string][rndmcard], 'of', card_class[class_string]
    cardvalue = face_cards[cards[class_string][rndmcard]]

    return (card_name)


# Returns the value for a players card
def card_vlu(card):
    return face_cards[card[0]]


# Prints a string about a cards contents
def cardstring(card):
    print(card[0], card[1], card[2])


# Creates sum of hands
def cardsum(card1, card2):
    return (card_vlu(card1) + card_vlu(card2))


# Determines if an Ace is hard or soft
def acecheck(card1, card2):
    if card_vlu(card1) + card_vlu(card2) < 12:
        face_cards['Ace'] = 11


# Adds card to used_list and makes sure no card can be drawn that has already been drawn.
def dupcheck(card):
    while card in used_cards:
        card = list(rndm_card())
        # I have tried 'return card' here with no luck
    while card not in used_cards:
        used_cards.append(card)

used_cards = []
print(used_cards)

input('Welcome to BlackJack! Press Enter to deal: ')
#Players hand
print('Your cards are: ')
player_1card1 = [6, 'of', 'Clubs']

while player_1card1 in used_cards:
    player_1card1 = list(rndm_card())

while player_1card1 not in used_cards:
    used_cards.append(player_1card1)

player_1card2 = [6, 'of', 'Clubs']
dupcheck(player_1card2)                #Code in function identical to code below yet does not work


# while player_1card2 in used_cards:   #When these five lines are un commented out the code works.        
#     player_1card2 = list(rndm_card())
#
# while player_1card2 not in used_cards:
#     used_cards.append(player_1card2)
acecheck(player_1card1,player_1card2)
print(used_cards)
cardstring(player_1card1)
cardstring(player_1card2)
print(cardsum(player_1card1,player_1card2))
```

Comment: `acecheck` and `dupchec` don't have any returns statements. should they be like that only?

Comment: I have actually tried using "return card" and it made no difference

Comment: There is a *lot* about this code where I can't really figure out how it's intended to work o_O I should offer some hints at least: the keys of dictionaries don't have to be integers (why not just use the suit names?), and if you want a random choice from a list, that is what `random.choice` is for - don't calculate an index yourself. Also, instead of trying to check for duplicate cards, try actually creating something that represents the deck - separately containing each card that it should - and taking the cards out from there.

Answer (score 0):

> however when I define the same code in a function it is not changing the value of a card that is already in the drawn cards list as intended.

It took me a long time to figure out what you were actually describing - i.e. what you expect to happen, and how it's different from what actually happens.

```
player_1card2 = [6, 'of', 'Clubs']
dupcheck(player_1card2)
```

This does not change the contents of `player_1card2` outside the function. Inside the function,

```
def dupcheck(card):
    while card in used_cards:
        card = list(rndm_card())
        # I have tried 'return card' here with no luck
    while card not in used_cards:
        used_cards.append(card)
```

`card = list(rndm_card())` creates a **new** value, and makes the **local** variable `card` be a name for that new value. It does not affect the passed-in list.

> I have tried 'return card' here with no luck

This is only half of the equation. You also need to **use** the returned value, for example `player_1card2 = dupcheck(player_1card2)`.

---

But really, the entire general approach is strange, in multiple ways. You don't choose a card from a deck by taking the six of clubs arbitrarily and then changing the selection until you have something that wasn't already picked. You choose a card from a deck by *putting everything that can be picked into the deck, and then picking one out* (you can even `random.shuffle` the deck and then take them off the end, rather than making a `random.choice` from the middle each time). Also, you clearly already know about lists, so why isn't the player's hand a list?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your time reviewing my code and giving pointers it is very meaningful as I am still learning and it is very valuable to hear input from experienced people.

Comment: With regards to the six of clubs statement that was actually something I forgot to explain. The original code uses list(rndm_card) to draw a random card using indexing. I purposely put 6 of clubs in an effort to test the function to see if it prevented duplicates. I did try player_1card2 = dupcheck(player_1card2) however when I changed the card to anything other than the value of player_1card1 I received numerous error messages.